# How to vertically center a responsive clipped image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, clipping, image-clipping

I'm trying to vertically center an image that is clipped. The image is responsive. On mobile, the image is full-size and looks good. But, when the browser gets extended say for a laptop, the entire bottom half of the image is cropped off and nothing gets cropped at the top.

I tried playing around with the numbers in CSS. If the image is around 800px wide, it shows better but still, all clipping is done at the bottom.

Any ideas that will get the image to center vertically and remain responsive would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

HTML:

```
  <div class="image-wrap" id="wrapper">
      <img src="cropped-img.jpg" alt="Oceanside Pier">
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-wrap {
    max-height: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%px;       
    -webkit-transition: max-width .5s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -moz-transition: max-width .5s ease-out;  /* FF4+ */
    -ms-transition: max-width .5s ease-out;  /* IE10? */
    -o-transition: max-width .5s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transition: max-width .5s ease-out;
}

    .image-wrap img {
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
        -moz-transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;  /* FF4+ */
        -ms-transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;  /* IE10? */
        -o-transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
        transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 100%px) {
    .image-wrap { max-width: 100%; }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
    var imageHeight, wrapperHeight, overlap, container = $('.image-wrap');  
 
    function centerImage() {
        imageHeight = container.find('img').height();
        wrapperHeight = container.height();
        overlap = (wrapperHeight - imageHeight) / 2;
        container.find('img').css('margin-top', overlap);
    }
     
    $(window).on("load resize", centerImage);
     
    var el = document.getElementById('wrapper');
    if (el.addEventListener) {  
        el.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", centerImage, false); // Webkit event
        el.addEventListener("transitionend", centerImage, false); // FF event
        el.addEventListener("oTransitionEnd", centerImage, false); // Opera event
    }
});
```

Comment: In image-wrap, you have max-width: 100%px; and in @media only screen and (min-width: 100%px). You might want to set both of those to simply 100%.

Comment: Oh good grief. Thanks for pointing that out. It didn't fix my issue, but it sure wasn't helping my cause.

Answer (score 0):

If i get right what you want to do, try commenting your js to center the image and use the following style

```
.image-wrap img {

    object-fit:cover;//you can also try "contain" here
    object-fit:center;

    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;  /* Saf3.2+, Chrome */
    -moz-transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;  /* FF4+ */
    -ms-transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;  /* IE10? */
    -o-transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;  /* Opera 10.5+ */
    transition: margin-top .5s ease-out;

}
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit

Comment: With 1 addition that worked MuhMarigo. I had to add `max-height: 450px;` to your css code. I was a little iffy about following up on object-fit, but it's such a good solution. And it works without all the JavaScript.